# How to have a SQLite query with a variable part?

Tags: sqlite

Hi I am trying to create a query for SQLite which has a variable part in it. By variable I mean that a certain part within the string can possibly contain a variable but also an empy value

I tried this but I am not sure whether this works.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE attr LIKE 'ABC% %DEF'`

Comment: Why are you not sure if this works ? Have you run it ?

Comment: If you are certain about your leading and lagging characters then use attr LIKE 'ABC%DEF' for anything in between including spaces.

Comment: Okay so a single % will do the job? Thanks! I am unsure because I am preparing some queries atm for tables that dont exist rn ^^

Comment: You can run your test using passing some values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding onto my comment, check the below code to test your values.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'ABC G DEF' LIKE 'ABC%DEF'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END as test_space,
       CASE WHEN 'ABCGGGDEF' LIKE 'ABC%DEF'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END AS test_all
```